# Java: Porting simple operations from Python to Java/ List Processing

Tags: java, python, multidimensional-array

In Python I can do some simple stuff like:

```
# declare lists
A =["a","bnbnb"]
B = [1,2,3]
C = ['x'] + A    # (Simple Append)

# iterate over both lists
for x in [A,B,C]:  # (Create list of lists on the fly for for loops)
    do something to X[0]
```

And so on.

I am new to Java - and understand that arrays are fixed size, but lists and array lists arent.
How would I mimic the above?

Here is my failed attempt

```
# declare lists
String[] A ={"a","bnbnb"}
String[] B = [1,2,3]
Stuck here C = ['x'] + A    (Simple Append)

# iterate over both lists
for x in [A,B,C]:  (Cant seem to do this either)
    # do something to X[0]
```

Using `ArrayList`s just kept making it more cumbersome - bet I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `List`s instead:

```
List<String> A = Arrays.asList("a", "bnbnb");
List<String> B = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");

// you have to do this in two steps:
List<String> C = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("x"));
C.addAll(A);

// iteration:
for (List<String> x : Arrays.asList(A, B, C)) {
    // do something to x.get(0), analogous to x[0] in Python    
}
```

(See [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29))

Comment: Got it - The example on the link makes this clear - List<String> stooges = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");

Comment: And for  [A,B,C]  is the equivalent List<List<String>> D = Arrays.asList(A,B,C) ?

Answer (score 0):

List would serve your purpose.

```
            String[] A ={"a","bnbnb"};
            String[] B = {"1","2","3"};
            List<String> C = new ArrayList<String>();

            C.add("X");
            Collections.addAll(C,A);

            System.out.print(C);
```

Comment: This isn't equivalent to the Python code. `C` should be a list of strings containing `["x","a","bnbnb"]`.